# Deleting module from front-end I Can't find in the back-end

Tags: module, module-display

I am very new to Joomla and I am responsible for updating a website that has been created by another web administrator. 
I have what I believe to be a module that I want to delete, I see it in the front end but have no idea where is it in the back-end. I looked everywhere (Modules, articles,...) but can't find it and the ex-web administrator skipped to give the module position in the administration guide. Please let me know where I should look in the back-end? Thank you

Comment: Does the module have a title associated with it? If so, search for that title in the Module Manager

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page where the module appears with a pointer as to which one you are trying to delete and it might help someone help you.

Comment: Define "front end" and "back end" so we know we're thinking about the same things when we see those words. As for position, you should be able to tell that from comparing "view source" in the browser with the template's index.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. 
@Lodder : The Module does not have a name associated to it, and I could not find it in the module Manager; I am even questioning if it is a Module at all as I investigated all the positions and it is in none of them. and when checking the "view source" it does not state it as a module. 
@ Irata : Here is the link to the page [link](http://neamtic.ioc-unesco.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=502&Itemid=513),

Comment: the "module" I want to delete is the table below the map containing the "National Tsunami warning center; Disaster management Office; Tsunami National Contact". It is a table that appears in all the country pages if you click on the flags in the upper part of the page.
@Arlen : the front end is the website (link above) the back end is the link provided/administrator/index.php. I checked the "view source" it does not state it is a Module, and now I have no idea what is it :D

Comment: Looks like it's article ID 502.

Comment: @Arlen Thank you! It worked! it was after all an article that I could edit! Thanks!